# ToggleButton inside LIstView

Tags: android, android-listview, togglebutton

I have a problem with `ToggleButton` inside `ListView`.

I am using `CursorAdapter` to fill `ListView`. The problem is that when I click on some `ToggleView` inside, LogCat show different id.

```
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {


        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.setalarm_item_switch);
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.setalarm_item_desc);

            id.setText(cursor.getString(ITEM_ID));


        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final View v) {

            Log.d("mojaapp", "Click on " + cursor.getINT(ITEM_ID));

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.setalarm_item, null);
        return view;

    }
```

Comment: It is allright, I  simplify this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not reading the **id** correctly from cursor. Do it like this:

```
Log.d("mojaapp", "Click on " + cursor.getINT(cursor.getColumnIndex(ITEM_ID)));
```

Comment: No, no I just wanted to make my problem more simplify